# How to call UseWebRoot in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, I could set `UseWebRoot()` like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
     .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
     .UseWebRoot(@".\WebSite\wwwroot\")
     .Build()
     .Run();
}
```

But I do not know how I should do it today because there is no such method anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 projects use the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0), by default. In the project templates, it's configured like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

In the example above, `webHostBuilder` is an implementation of [`IWebHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostbuilder), which still contains the [`UseWebRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.usewebroot) extension method. That means you can call it as you did for 2.2, but it's just moved to inside the delegate passed in to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`  shown above. Here's the complete example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webHostBuilder.UseWebRoot(@".\WebSite\wwwroot\");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For 3.0 use `CreateDefaultBuilder` instead:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseWebRoot("")
```

Comment: does not have any effect. with or without it - when running from VS, all works fine, when running binaries as a service - none of the wwwroot folder files are accessible, chdrome dev tools show `missing resource`